# Analogy Between Momentum and Faraday's Law of Induction

Tags: momentum, acceleration

What is the reason behind momentum, during acceleration?
 Mass resist velocity change during acceleration similar to Coiled wire resisting Current amount change.
The similarity is worth looking at.
Has anyone until today looked at this phenomenal similarity?

Comment: Yes. Modelling mass related systems with LC Circuits are common practice. maybe I should rephrase my question as= Analogy between mass inertia and Magnetic field inertia should motivate us the find the common root cause.

Comment: Such a similarity must have provoked much more. Inertia and gravity are still a mystery